# is-open not working properly on a ng-repeat list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

let's say that in my js file, i have the set the following:

```
var movies = [
     {'name':'Great Gatsby', 'selectedMovie':'false'},
     {'name':'Lego Movie', 'selectedMovie':'true'},
     {'name':'The Hobbit', 'selectedMovie':'false'}
]

$scopeObj.movieList = {
    movies:movies
}
```

and in my html file, i have the following:

```
<accordion close-others="true">
    <accordion-group ng-repeat="movie in movieList.movies" is-open="movie.selectedMovie">
        <accordion-heading>{{movie.name}}</accordion-heading>
        {{movie.name}}
    </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

when i go to my html page, it lists all the movies fine, but the second movie isn't expanded.  and it seems that trying to expanding any other movie fails.

i'm using angularjs 1.1

Comment: What library is 'accordion-group' defined in?

Comment: it's part of http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: here's a sample plunker i used: http://plnkr.co/edit/dnjhuFLRRo8U1TU7tLDW?p=preview
as you can see, first element's isOpen is false and second element's isOpen is true, yet in the preview, both are true.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm not terribly experience with plunkr, but this is what I came up with:

http://plnkr.co/edit/DRIXeDrg2AODxCH0l1Nh?p=preview

I believe the problem is that is-open is not an angular attribute, so you can't directly use an angular expression.  You have to use the standard binding syntax to read from the angular scope.  Try something like this:

```
<accordion close-others="true">
    <accordion-group ng-repeat="movie in movieList.movies" is-open="{{movie.selectedMovie}}">
        <accordion-heading>{{movie.name}}</accordion-heading>
        {{movie.name}}
    </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

It seemed to work in the plunkr.